# Laplace transform on an initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems, inverse-laplace

So i have been trying to solve this Laplace transform for some time now. I have asked my assistant teacher and he also was not able to solve it, so i will try here. problem:
$$
y'''- y = -ye^{2t}, \ \ \ \ \ y(0) = 0 , \ \ y'(0)=-1, \ \ y''(0)=-3.
$$
Have tried some different approaches with getting the same $Y(s)$ value and also tried to Taylor expand $Y(s-2)$ and also tried it this way:

$$
\mathscr{L} \{ y''' \} = s^3Y(s)-s^2(0)-s(-1)+3 \\
\mathscr{L} \{ y\} = Y(s) \\
\mathscr{L} \{ ye^{2t}\} = Y(s-2)
$$

$$
s^3Y(s)+s+3-Y(s)=Y(s-2) \Longrightarrow Y(s)(s^3-1)=Y(s-2)-s-3
$$

$$
Y(s) = \frac{Y(s-2)}{s^3-1}-\frac{s}{s^3-1}-\frac{3}{s^3-1}
$$
And from here on i have also tried to get something that makes sense.
Problem is found here on a exercise sheet under the ["Recommended Exercises"] https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4130/2021h/exercise_04.pdf.
And since its under recommended exercises we dont have a solutions manual for it...

Comment: Given the other exercises, this could be a typo and there should be $e^{2t}$ only?

Comment: I also think it's a typo, because  you would have to write the solution as the convolution of $L^{-1} (Y(s-2))$ and $L^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{s^3-1} \right)$...

Comment: Almost certainly a typo.  Without the initial condition, Wolfram|Alpha can't describe the solution using anything simpler than hypergeometric functions; with the IC, the free version can't figure out the constants of integration before it runs out of time and gets cut off.